# How to really disable Thunderbird updates?

Tags: updates, thunderbird

In Ubuntu 22.04, I want to stop Thunderbird from updating due to [this bug](https://blog.thunderbird.net/2023/01/important-message-for-microsoft-office-365-enterprise-users/) which prevents access to MS 365 (needed for my professional email). I followed the instructions and downgraded Thunderbird to an older version, but it still updates automatically to the most recent version every day.

Yesterday I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980412/how-to-disable-thunderbird-auto-update), using the `about:config` method to disable `app.update.auto`... But today it went back to the most recent version again, so this is not working.

I'm confused how these updates happen: are these regular updates from Ubuntu or specific to Thunderbird?

How can I disable Thunderbird updates?

Comment: How was Thunderbird installed? Is it a snap app or traditional "deb" install?

Comment: @user68186 Thank you, it was installed with the regular `apt` system, I'm going to try `apt-mark hold` as suggested in the link, maybe this is what I'm missing. I'm confused though, because I don't think Ubuntu asked me to do any update these past few days.

Comment: Ubuntu does not ask you about all updates. The default setting is to install security updates without asking you (it's a setting -- you can change that). At least one recent Thunderbird update was a security update.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for the explanation, it's certainly what happened indeed.